# php getimagesize errors

Tags: php, getimagesize

Im trying to get the image size for an image in my server and the data is in a database or my getimagesize function looks like this

```
$size = getimagesize(upload/$array['image']);
print_r($size);
```

I get these errors back...

```
Warning: Division by zero in /home/content/44/8713044/html/view/home/home.html on line 81

Warning: getimagesize() [function.getimagesize]: Filename cannot be empty in /home/content/44/8713044/html/view/home/home.html on line 81
```

the image is in the right place...what am I doing wrong?

Comment: note that many times, the first error is the error that matters. in this case it is telling you that you attempted to divide a number by zero (see the answers below). It seems obvious that you did not mean to divide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your path isn't in quotes, so it's not a string.

```
$size = getimagesize(upload/$array['image']);
```

It's trying to mathematically divide a constant named `upload` by `$array['image']`.

Use quotes and concatenate like this:

```
$size = getimagesize('upload/' . $array['image']);
```

Answer (score 1):

you should quote the string like this :

```
getimagesize("upload/{$array['image']}");
```

otherwise, PHP will treat this as a mathematic expression

this url might help :- http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.expressions.php